# copying a Postgres database when there is not much space left on the main server

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres/Timescale db on a server that has 2 TB of disk space. There is about 1.5 TB in use, so I can't make a copy of the tables on that server.

I need to make a copy of that db on a local hard drive and ship it to a client.

The server is remote, I don't have physical access to it, and I can't add space to it.

Given the size of the data, I can expect network interruptions or various issues before it's finished, so I need a solution that can resume the transfer.

What would be the best way to replicate it locally?

Comment: What does local mean, local to who? The server or your own machine? Can you not just mount a file share on the server and do `pgdump` to it? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930923/postgresql-where-does-the-output-of-pg-dump-go

Comment: @Charlieface the server is in another country and, by local, I meant a computer physically sitting next to me. I cannot do a dump on the remote server since there is not enough space and I can't rely on the connection to be stable, so I need to be able to resume the transfer from where it stopped.

Comment: Then maybe create a cloud file share in that country and mount that to the server.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: "I don't have physical access to it"  Well, what *can* you do?

Comment: 1.5 TB will most likely compress to less than 0.5TB using a good compression program.

Comment: @jjanes we’re using Timescale compressed tables right now so I still need space for the export which might be too big for the storage

Comment: I don't have much experience with TS compressed tables, but it certainly wouldn't surprise me if they do compress better than 3x. Compression which needs to work with random access is generally pretty bad compression.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [Barman server](https://docs.pgbarman.org/release/3.5.0/#two-typical-scenarios-for-backups) locally, with the `rsync` backup method to deal with network interruptions. You could then ship the backup itself to your client, or restore it locally and do a `pg_dump` export.

Comment: I will have a look at that. Thanks!